# How can we check if a AutomationElement is selected c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

Is there any way to get if an AutomationElement  is selected or not. I have used following code to get an AutomationElement  object.

```
System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
AutomationElement  element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
//how to know element is selected or not
```

Comment: Do you mean 'selected' or 'focused'?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectionItem` pattern to determine if an element is selected or not (obviously, not all AutomationElements implement this pattern -- only those that can actually be selected. In case they don't, you may use the `IsFocused` property).